# Linux: setting process priority AND dynamically loading libraries

Tags: scheduling, linux-capabilities

I have a linux application which loads *.so libraries using a modified `rpath` (set during installation).  It also needs to run with realtime priority.

To get realtime priority it does this:

```
sched_param sched;
sched.sched_priority = 70;
sched_setscheduler(getpid(), SCHED_FIFO, &sched);
```

However [`sched_setscheduler`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/sched_setscheduler.2.en.html) is a privilaged method, protected by the [`CAP_SYS_NICE`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/capabilities.7.en.html) capability. Therefore, to get realtime priority without running as root, I add [`setcap`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libcap2-bin/setcap.8.en.html) to my `postinst`:

```
setcap cap_sys_nice+ep /path/to/myapp
```

However, [linux decides](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=448594) that programs should not be allowed to load libraries from `rpath` if they have extra capabilities.

Is there a way for me to set my own priority **and** load rpath libraries?

Note: I'd prefer to do this in the application or in the `postinst`.  I'd like to avoid deploying scripts as the only way to launch the application.  I know `sudo chrt -f -p 70 $!` could do it from a script.

Comment: You can try `dlopen` to explicitly load the desired library using it's full path.

Comment: Tried this out.  Apparently it's not just dynamically loaded libraries, it's **any** library which uses the rpath. So if I link to a *.so at compile time and install both binaries togeather, I still get the problem.  Note that I'm installing to `/opt/..` so the libraries can't be installed in the normal system directories.  I've edited my question to exclude the word "dynamic"

Comment: Well, you can always tweak the libc. It's not as bad as it sounds - it's done all the time on embedded. For glibc, you'd just want to make sure that `__libc_enable_secure` global never gets set to 1. Otherwise you're bound by secure execution rules, as listed here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solutions which do not involve modifying `libc`.  Both solutions require us to replace the calls to `sched_setscheduler()` with a call to launch another process directly.

1. Install a file to `/etc/sudoers.d/` with the following line:

   ```
   %users ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chrt
   ```

   Then from our application launch `sudo` as a process with arguments `chrt -f -p X Y` where `X` is the configured priority and `Y` is the result of `getpid()`.
2. Create a custom `chrt` with:

   ```
   cp $(which chrt) $(DESTDIR)/bin/chrt
   sudo setcap cap_sys_nice+ep $(DESTDIR)/bin/chrt
   sudo chmod 755 $(DESTDIR)/bin/chrt
   ```

   Then from our application launch `chrt` as a process with arguments `-f -p X Y`

Not sure which solution is better.  Note this is effectively embedded (or at least purpose built) so I'm not too worried about the security exposure.